# P2P network implementation: how to avoid "orphan" groups of nodes

Tags: graph, networks, p2p

As the title says, in a P2P decentralized network implementation how do you ensure that all your nodes are actually connected and you never have a subset of "orphan" nodes at any time (e.g. nodes connected to each others but "disconnected" from the rest of the graph)?

Looking for ideas/suggestions/algorithms/strategies...

Comment: If all nodes must be connected, then in what way is it decentralised? If there is a defined list of nodes that must be connected, then they are not just centralised, they are for all intents and purposes a single indivisible unit.

Comment: One way you can solve this is by electing one of the nodes as a Leader.  See [The Raft Consensus Algorithm](http://thesecretlivesofdata.com/raft/) for a robust way to do that.

Comment: @Steve I didn't ever say that there is a defined list of nodes, neither that every single node must be connected to each other. Your answer points that you didn't pay attention to the question, but thanks for trying.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you very much for the link!

Comment: @Piero, but if there's no defined list of nodes, how can anyone possibly tell whether all members are present? And if you *can't* tell that all members are present, how can you possibly determine whether two or more nodes have formed an orphan network between themselves? It's a simple question of logic, old chap.

Comment: It depends on whether nodes can go offline temporarily.  If any single node can't go offline then when patching or maintenance is needed then ALL the nodes have to go offline at once because if they don't then they won't be connected to all the nodes.  If a single node can go offline then it might be the only connection between two halves of the graph, so how do the rest of the nodes know that?  IF you use the Raft Consensus then you need to know the number of nodes so you know how big the majority is.  So how do you know the number of nodes if the graph is split in two while a node joins?

Comment: @Steve Regarding your first question, there's not a predefined list of members, and the network would/should work with any number of nodes connected at any time. For your second question.... that's exactly what I was asking in the first place: methodologies to ensure that we don't fall in this situation, given that nodes can connect/disconnect at any time and the number of nodes is not fixed nor predetermined.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Nodes can connect and disconnect at any time, and as you pointed out it's exactly the reason why I'm concerned about potential graph splits. I had a look at Raft Consensus, but I'm not sure on how well it would scale with a large network... having only one leader seems to me like having a single point of failure, for example: what would refrain one malicious node to set a lower timeout to candidate itself for the election? If it wins and is elected as leader, it will hold the entire network in his hands.

Comment: If a bunch of people on Earth run your program, and a bunch of people on Mars run your program, how will the Earth ones know they're supposed to be connected to the Mars ones? They won't.

Comment: @user253751 I'm Sorry but to be honest from your comment I think you don't understand what we're talking about here... maybe you can first read the question and some of the answers to better understand the subject of the discussion. Thank you

Comment: @Piero My "answer" is: you can't actually guarantee it, because some people on Earth might be running your program, and some people on Alpha Centauri might be running your program, and it's impossible for each group of nodes to know that the other one exists, much less that it's disconnected from it.

Comment: @user253751 Yeah sorry for using the incorrect term to refer to the comments and thank you for your correction. Anyway, we're talking about P2P so it's obvious that when a single node starts it will have a way to "know" that it must connect to someone (and also to whom). Given this assumption, I'm talking about what will happen "after". And I know for sure that there are ways to do what I'm asking (otherwise cryptocurrencies wouldn't exist, for example).... I simply don't know "how" and I'm asking for pointers and ideas :)

Comment: In your system, does every node know about every other node? Or just the ones it's connected to?

Comment: @user253751 There's not a restriction on this aspect, but I think that a good idea would be that every node knows of all connected nodes to the network (even if not directly connected to him). My question is: having all this information on each node, which could be a good strategy/algorithm to ensure that a node that disconnects from the network doesn't break the graph in two halves? I hope that now my question is more clear...

Comment: @Piero, you seem reluctant to confront the idea that you're asking for the impossible. You can't have a "decentralised/P2P" setup, and also a guarantee that two separate networks cannot form. And if any node somehow forms a unique bridge between two separate areas of the network, then inevitably the loss of that node will sunder the network into two orphans. The only logical way to handle the problem is either to have a defined authority, or to have a list of nodes and require at least a majority to be present - only this can guarantee the absence of a second orphan network.

Comment: I think it is possible if each node has a list of all the nodes that is kept up to date and changes to the list are communicated.  You still have the problem that a malicious node that is the connection between two halves might not pass on the messages so that each half still thinks they are connected to the whole graph.  So if you can't trust the nodes then you probably can't do it because a graph of nodes will always depend on the honesty of the node connecting both halves.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ensure this 100%. Some people might run your program on Earth. And some aliens might run the same program on Alpha Centauri. And there's no way for your program on Alpha Centauri to know that Earth *exists* - it certainly can't know that some people on Earth are running your program and that it's not connected to them.

The best you can do is to guess. If every node in your network knows about every other node in the network:

- If the network size suddenly shrank by more than half, it *probably* partitioned and you're in the small part.
- If the network size suddenly shrank by less than half but more than one node, it *probably* partitioned and you're in the big part.
- If you try to connect to a node and that node knows about a bunch of nodes that you don't, there was a partition and you're now fixing it.

If your node knows about all the connections in the network, it could identify nodes that it has a "poorly redundant" connection to, and try to establish connections to them, to make it harder for the network to partition.

If your node doesn't know about the overall network state... then this is an even harder problem to solve. Many people have designed solutions that hopefully work most of the time.

Algorithms like Raft seem to be designed for servers with mutual trust to reach consensus. When they don't have mutual trust, there is solution called "blockchain". It's like voting but it votes by wasting electricity, and then rewards computers which voted for the thing that won the election. It wastes more electricity than the entire country of Austria, so you don't want to go there.